# How to pass multiple array values as format args?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, printwriter

Using writer.format and passing a predefined format string (%5s%10s...), what's the best way to parse an array of Strings as separate arguments?

So if I have:

```
Printwriter writer = new Printwriter ("table.txt");
String[] columns = {"Name", "Month", "Day"};
String form_string = "%20s%10s%5s";
```

How can I pass the array elements name, month, and day as arg1, arg2, arg3 in:

```
writer.format(form_string, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Comment: Can we get some examples in the question please

Comment: Stay with `writer.format(form_string, columns[0], columns[1], columns[2]);`. Clearest. P.S. Why not "%-20s" for left aligned padding?

Comment: The problem is that the array is arbitrary, the code is in a function that takes the string array as its arg so I won't know the length or contents of the array

Comment: You can use a for loop to loop through columns and append it to a string, then store the string. If you need sample code just tell me, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Ya I'm not sure exactly how to implement that, since I would need each String in columns[] to be a specific argument to format. Code would be appreciate d

Answer (score 0):

since java 1.5 the PrintWriter class has a method **printf** (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which can help you because it admits just an array of parameters.

here you have a snippet code:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
String[] columns = {"Name", "Month", "Day"};
String form_string = "%20s%10s%5s";
writer.printf(form_string,columns);
writer.flush();
```

the output is just formatted in the desired format.

```
            Name     Month  Day
```

Hope this helps!